# Error when trying to combine commands in one line, including Db2 query

Tags: sql, database, db2, ksh, aix

I am facing a problem when trying to run a Db2 query.

If I run

```
sudo su - user
db2 connect to DATABASE
db2 -x "select * from SCHEMA"
```

I receive the output.

Now, if I do this

```
sudo su - user -c " db2 connect to DATABASE && db2 -x "select * from SCHEMA" "
```

I face this error

```
SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003
```

This is strange because at first, this command was working perfectly, and now, it's not working.

What is wrong?

Comment: You changed the commands, added `-c` and not use `;` to delimit commands.

Comment: Instead of ';' I am using '&&'

Comment: Even with ';' The error it's the same.

Comment: You must use escaping. Try this: `sudo su - user -c " db2 connect to DATABASE && db2 -x \"select * from SCHEMA\""`

Comment: The same error appears

Comment: Does the following work? `sudo su - user -c "db2 connect to DATABASE && db2 -x \"VALUES 1\""`

Comment: Nop. Actually, the same error appears.

Comment: Some strange shell for the user? `grep '^user:' /etc/passwd | cut -d':' -f7`

Comment: Output: /usr/bin/ksh

Comment: Do you see any messages in the db2diag.log on server after issuing this command?

Comment: Combining the Db2 statements into one CLP invocation: `sudo su - user -c "db2 \"connect to DATABASE;select * from SCHEMA\" "`

Comment: @data_henrik It won't work. It should be something like this: `sudo su - user -c "echo -e 'connect to DATABASE; \n select * from SCHEMA;' | db2 +p -tv -"`. AIX `echo` doesn't require `-e` afaik to interpret `\n` correctly.

Comment: @data_henrik I tried and didn't work.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I tried and this error appeared DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003



select * from SCHEMA.output
SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003

Comment: Did I get you correct, that `sudo su - user -c "db2 \"connect to DATABASE\""` works, but the the following doesn't work? `sudo su - user -c "db2 connect to DATABASE && db2 -x \"select * from SCHEMA\""`

Comment: Unfortunately, both commands are not working.

Comment: This means, that the problem is not with the db2 commands combination as you originally stated. The problem is, that db2 commands don't work at all with `sudo` in your environment. So, you should either edit this question accordingly, say, like: 2 sequential commands `sudo su - user` and `db2 connect to DATABASE` work, but not as a single command `sudo su - user -c "db2 connect to DATABASE"`, or ask another question closing this one.

Comment: Maybe something like this: `echo -e 'connect to DATABASE;\nselect * from SCHEMA;' | sudo su - user -c 'db2 -x'`

Comment: @MarkBarinstein but before I was doing with success this command, and now it's not working. Maybe some configuration was made?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond same error

Comment: Whenever your try something, please edit your Original Post, quote the command you tried and the error message you got.

Comment: I am getting this same issue except I haven't been able to ever get any of the commands to work unless I run them in separate steps.